# Vue.js - Update Array with current localStorage at refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to check for the localStorage when at a page reload, if there is already an item there and if yes, I want to update "cryptocurreny" with the current values (title & value).

When I add something with my `addCrypto()` function, my localStorage looks like this:

> [{"name":"ETH","value":"1.5"},{"name":"BTC","value":"2.75"}]

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div v-for="coin in cryptocurrency">
      <input v-model="coin.name">
      <input v-model="coin.value">
    </div>
    <button @click="addCrypto">
      New Cryptocurreny
    </button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      cryptocurrency: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    set_data() {
      localStorage.setItem( 'cryptocurrencies', JSON.stringify(this.cryptocurrency) );
      this.cryptocurrency = this.get_data();
    },
    get_data(){
      return localStorage.getItem('cryptocurrencies');
    },
    addCrypto() {
      localStorage.setItem( 'cryptocurrencies', JSON.stringify(this.cryptocurrency) );
      this.cryptocurrency.push({ name: '', value: ''});
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But I tried to add `localStorage.getItem('cryptocurrencies');` at the end of my `addCrypto()` function but I get errors and at a page reload my `cryptocurreny` variable is empty.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: I have a simple script you can follow that can be of help if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really work out what you're doing, but from what I see the `set_data()` function isn't called anywhere?

You'll want to use the mounted or created hook ([see which one suits you](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)) and do the check in there.

**Example**

```
mounted () {
  const saved = localStorage.getItem('cryptocurrencies')
  if (saved) {
    this.cryptocurrency = saved
  }
}
```

You could put that code into it's own method and call that in `mounted()` of course.